# 50% of my chrome extension users disappear, ideas?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

- My extension has a few hundred downloads daily.
- For every user that installs I create a user in my database.
- I report back to the server that the user is still active every time the extension starts and every 2-3 (random range) hours after that.
- I've set the uninstall url so when a user uninstalls the extension a page opens and I mark the user as uninstalled.

I see roughly 10% uninstall rate within two days of the install.

The problem is that 50% of the users disappear, meaning they do not report activity for a week or more.

I've managed to rule out:

- Users disabling the extension.
- Users syncing the extension across machines, then removing on one machine which removes it from the rest of the machines.

What else can it be???

Did anyone else experience that?

Comment: Maybe they close the tab with uninstall url instantly before the connection is established? This is a subconscious habit that developed over the years when many sites opened popups unexpectedly (lots of computer users don't use ad-blockers/popup-blockers, I'd rather say the majority).

Comment: Might be, but I can't see how it can explain such a high rate.
But it's a good idea to explore, it might explain some of this phenomena.

Comment: Easy. Lots of people are curious, they install it, find out that it's not what they want and uninstall it.

Comment: I'm fine with that, the issue is that when someone uninstalls it I can track and see he\she uninstalled, but 50% just disappear without uninstall.

Comment: Oh, they might simply uninstall it later not being connected to the internet if they use laptops with wifi or other mobile internet connection and so on.